# Angular-Slickgrid: Not all filters appear in headerrow

Tags: angular, typescript, slickgrid

FOR DOCUMENTATION:
I found the problem and a solution:

We use numeric id's in our dataset (like 1,2,3,...). Somewhere in the code, the grid get confused and maps the wrong columns with id's: 
When i ask the div with grid.getHeaderRowColumn(col.id) and fill it with col.id it shows a different id then col.id ! 
Useless to say that in the same time not all colomns are found (so not all filters can be set witch was my original problem). 
Changing the id to a string ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', ...) solved the problem !

I don't know if this is a bug or simply an impossibility with dynamic columns but using only strings as id's does the trick for now. Thanx @ghiscoding for the help.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have this strange problem:

When i build my slickgrid, not all columns have a filter-Input-box in the header row (although they should have, regarding my column definitions).

When i add (of remove) columns, other filterboxes appear/disappear, whithout changing the other column-definitions. So it seems to appear randomly (although using the same columns, the same filters appear/disappear).

Using plain slickgrid, i can set these filters manualy to correct this problem. But how can i do this with angular-slickgrid ?

Anny suggestions ?

I use angular-slickgrid version 2.15.4.

EDIT

this are my gridOptions and ColumnDefinitions.
(they are constructed dynamicly, but this is from dev-tools just before initiating the grid)

```
columnDefinitions: {
    0: {id: 6, …}
    1: {id: 2, …}
    2: {
        id: 4
        fieldtype: "string"
        name: "deliveryaddressadditionalline"
        json_translate_property: null
        field: "deliveryaddressadditionalline"
        detailparams: {edit: true, tab: {…}, card: {…}}
        gridparams: {show: true, edit: false}
        filterable: true
        sortable: true
        type: 1
        editor: {model: ƒ}
        filter: {model: ƒ}
        grouping: {getter: "deliveryaddressadditionalline", collapsed: false, formatter: ƒ}
        rerenderOnResize: true
        }
    3: {
        id: "edit"
        name: ""
        field: ""
        width: 30
        formatter: ƒ (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext)
        onCellClick: (e, args) => { this.gotoDetailPane(e, args, detailInfo); }
        gridparams: {show: true}
        fieldtype: "edit"
        }
    4: {id: 1, fieldtype: "string", name: "id", json_translate_property: null, field: "id", …}
}

gridOptions: {
    enableColumnPicker: false
    headerMenu: {hideColumnHideCommand: true}
    enableGridMenu: false
    enableAutoResize: true
    autoResize: {containerId: "grid-container", sidePadding: 15}
    enableSorting: undefined
    autoEdit: false
    editable: true
    enableCellNavigation: true
    enableFiltering: true
    rowSelectionOptions: {selectActiveRow: true}
    enableRowSelection: true
    showHeaderRow: true
    showTopPanel: false
    enableDraggableGrouping: true
    createPreHeaderPanel: true
    showPreHeaderPanel: false
    preHeaderPanelHeight: 40
    draggableGrouping: {
        dropPlaceHolderText: "Drop a column header here to group by the column", 
        deleteIconCssClass: "fa fa-times", 
        onGroupChanged: ƒ, 
        onExtensionRegistered: ƒ
    }
    explicitInitialization: true
}
```

and this is the result (multiple situations: columns are shuffled, filters appear at random while code is the same):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need 2 flags for Filters to show up, `enableFiltering: true` in the Grid Options and then  `filterable: true` on each column you want to use a Filter. Lastly, if you didn't define which Filter to use, then the default is a input text filter. This is all assumptions since you didn't provide any code sample of what you're doing. If your problem is more with dynamic column definitions, well that's another reason I never use column definitions dynamically.

Comment: BTW you should always provide some code of what you try, else you'll end up not receiving any answers to your question.

Comment: I've added some code. Input is created dynamicly, so difficult to post, but this is wat goes into the grid.

Comment: It seems you've put the output result instead of the actual column definitions, it's a bit hard to find the problem when you're missing all the commas between each property and I have to assume that `fieldtype: "string"` is actually `fieldtype: FieldType.string`. I'll have to say again though, I never use dynamically created columns and NEVER EVER do dynamic Grid Options, you're looking for trouble. In our project we have certain column definitions that get loaded after knowing the users security group level, so we build the grid with an `ngIf` in the View and it fixes all our issues.

Comment: Found the problem: We use numeric id's in our dataset (like 1,2,3,...). Somewhere in the code, the grid get confused and maps the wrong columns with id's: When i ask the div with grid.getHeaderRowColumn(col.id) and fill it with col.id it shows a different id then col.id ! Useless to say that in the same time not all colomns are found (so not all filters can be set witch was my problem). Changing the id to a string ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', ...) solved the problem !

Comment: Glad you found it, indeed we can use numbers as id but I always use strings. It might be because in the code somewhere it uses the `+` and that makes a sum instead of aggregating the strings. If that is the case, maybe changing the number `1` into `"1"` might have worked. but still I prefer to use string indeed, less problems

Answer (score 1):

Note that the first two lines of `getHeaderRowColumn` are

```
function getHeaderRowColumn(columnIdOrIdx) {
  var idx = (typeof columnIdOrIdx === "number" ? columnIdOrIdx : getColumnIndex(columnIdOrIdx));
```

so if the passed parameter is a number, it is interpreted as the 0-based index of the columns array (*not* the id). If the parameter is a string, then the column array index is looked up, treating the parameter as the id.

So your solution is correct; if the id is numeric, simply convert it to a string before passing it.

Note this is true generally in a lot of cases for javascript objects: `o[2]` will attempt to look up the second element of an array, whereas `o['2']` will look up an object property called '2'. The code above is not dependent on an object, but the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and a solution:

We use numeric id's in our dataset (like 1,2,3,...). Somewhere in the code, the grid get confused and maps the wrong columns with id's: When i ask the div with grid.getHeaderRowColumn(col.id) and fill it with col.id it shows a different id then col.id ! Useless to say that in the same time not all columns are found (so not all filters can be set witch was my original problem). Changing the id to a string ('id1', 'id2', 'id3', ...) solved the problem !

I don't know if this is a bug or simply an impossibility with dynamic columns but using only strings as id's does the trick for now. Thanx @ghiscoding for the help.